# where do i incorporate that no body has won, in my tic-tac-toe game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to coding and has recently started learning python. My first challenge is to build a tic tac toe game. Below are my codes for the game, everything worked fine except that when there is no winner(i.e. game draw); i want to display `no body has won the game.` I've tried to incorporate an `else` in various places. but, they didn't help. Here is my code.

```
  # a dictionary to display the grid
grid = {
    '1':'1', '2':'2', '3':'3',
    '4':'4', '5':'5', '6':'6',
    '7':'7', '8':'8', '9':'9'
}
# a list to store the values that has already been entered
used_places = []

# players and their symbols
player_1 = 'x'
player_2 = 'o'

# to store result
result = None

def grid_display():
    #this function displays the grid
    print('\n\n')
    print(grid['1'], '\t|\t', grid['2'], '\t|\t', grid['3'])
    print(''.rjust(19,'*'))
    print(grid['4'], '\t|\t', grid['5'], '\t|\t', grid['6'])
    print(''.rjust(19, '*'))
    print(grid['7'], '\t|\t', grid['8'], '\t|\t', grid['9'])

def win_the_game():
    # this function checks for result and returns true or false
    if(
        (grid['1'] == grid['2'] == grid['3']) or (grid['4'] == grid['5'] == grid['6']) or
        (grid['7'] == grid['8'] == grid['9']) or (grid['1'] == grid['4'] == grid['7']) or
        (grid['2'] == grid['5'] == grid['8']) or (grid['3'] == grid['6'] == grid['9']) or
        (grid['1'] == grid['5'] == grid['9']) or (grid['3'] == grid['5'] == grid['7'])
    ):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def taking_turns(turn):
    #this function asks user for input
    print("its turn of ", turn)
    choice = input("enter your choice")
    while not (choice.isdecimal() and choice in grid and (choice not in used_places)):
    # taking proper input by checkin it with already entered numbers
    # and if it is a number
    # and if number is in between 1 and 9
        choice = input("\nenter your choice properly:")

    player_move(choice, turn)

def player_move(move, assign):
    # this function fills the entered numbers into used_places list
    # and replaces numbers in grid with user input
    used_places.append(move)
    grid[move] = assign

print("player 1 : 'X'")
print("player 2 : 'O'")

for i in range(0,10):               # loops 9 times to play the game
    if i % 2 == 0:                  # giving turns. if i is even, player 1 gets turn and odd, player 2
        grid_display()              # displaying complete grid
        turn = player_1             # to display whose turn it is; refer the function
        taking_turns(turn)
        if win_the_game() == True:  # if the called function returns true in this 'if'
            result = turn           # player 1 wins
            break
    else:
        grid_display()              # same code as above
        turn = player_2
        taking_turns(turn)

        if win_the_game() == True:
            result = turn
            break

print('\n\n',result, "won the game!!")     # printing result
```

Comment: Outside the for loop - if `win_the_game()` is `False` then no-one's won...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting result = None, set result = 'Nobody'.

Looking at your logic, you only set result if somebody wins, this would leave the default of result to nobody.

-- edit --

Sorry, I kinda got carried away and re-wrote the logic of your game in proving my solution. Take it or leave it, but it works great now and maybe you can use it as an example to fix your own.

```
import os

# a dictionary to display the grid
grid = {
    '1':'1', '2':'2', '3':'3',
    '4':'4', '5':'5', '6':'6',
    '7':'7', '8':'8', '9':'9'
}
# a list to store the values that are available
places = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

# to store result
result = 'Nobody'

# starting player
turn = 'O'

# display a game grid
def grid_display():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    #this function displays the grid
    print
    print(grid['1'], '|', grid['2'], '|', grid['3'])
    print(''.rjust(25,'*'))
    print(grid['4'], '|', grid['5'], '|', grid['6'])
    print(''.rjust(25, '*'))
    print(grid['7'], '|', grid['8'], '|', grid['9'])

# check to see if anyone has won or are we out of moves
def win_the_game():
    # this function checks for result and returns true or false
    if(
        (grid['1'] == grid['2'] == grid['3']) or (grid['4'] == grid['5'] == grid['6']) or
        (grid['7'] == grid['8'] == grid['9']) or (grid['1'] == grid['4'] == grid['7']) or
        (grid['2'] == grid['5'] == grid['8']) or (grid['3'] == grid['6'] == grid['9']) or
        (grid['1'] == grid['5'] == grid['9']) or (grid['3'] == grid['5'] == grid['7'])
    ):
        return True

    # checks if there are any moves left
    elif not places:
        return False

    else:
        return False

# input / grid update function
def taking_turns():
    # this function asks user for input
    # use RAW_INPUT to make it a string
    print
    print map(str, places)
    choice = raw_input("\nEnter "+turn+"'s choice: ")

    if choice in places:
        # this removes the number from the available list
        # and replaces numbers in grid with user input
        places.remove(choice)
        grid[choice] = turn


# Logic loop
while places:
        grid_display()                      # always display the grid
        if turn == "O":                     # giving turns.
            turn = 'X'
            taking_turns()
            if win_the_game() == True:      # if the called function returns true in this 'if'
                result = turn               # player 1 wins
                grid_display()              # Winners GRID
                break
        else:
            turn = 'O'
            taking_turns()
            if win_the_game() == True:
                result = turn
                grid_display()              # Winners GRID
                break

# results
print
print(result, "won the game!!")             # printing result
print
```

Comment: the output is
x  |  o  |  x
*******************
x  |  o  |  o
*******************
o  |  x  |  x
its turn of  o
enter your choice

Comment: def win_the_game():
    # this function checks for result and returns true or false
    if(
        

    ):
        return True
    else:
        return 'no body won'

Comment: that is where i edited the code. that didn't help. as i stated in question, it keeps asking for input. thanks for your time.